# buster.js why is my testcase getting skipped?

Tags: javascript, buster.js

I keep getting this message after running `$ buster test`:

```
Skipping Test name, unsupported requirement: is_a
```

I also get `Passed: is_a is_a`.

Not sure what these cryptic messages mean. I did define a method "is_a" on Object, so that might be the culprit, but I'm not sure why that would mess with the buster tests.